# How do I combine these two SQLite queries?

Tags: android, sqlite

How do I combine these two queries into a single query to get the last 10 messages, using the `LIMIT` keyword?

```
Cursor cursor0 = db.query(Chat_MESSAGE, messagecolumns, senderid + "=? AND " + receiverid + "=?", new String[] {
            sender_id, receiver_id }, null, null, null, null);

Cursor cursor1 = db.query(Chat_MESSAGE, messagecolumns, senderid + "=? AND " + receiverid + "=?", new String[] {
            receiver_id, sender_id }, null, null, null, null);
```

Table is

```
chat id sender_id receiver_id message
   1        1       2            hii
   2        1       2            hello
   3        2       1            good
   4        2       1            nice
   5        1       5            hii
```

I want to get 1-4 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are your original two conditions:

```
senderid = ? AND receiverid = ?
```

```
receiverid = ? AND senderid = ?
```

To combine them, use OR:

```
(senderid = ? AND receiverid = ?) OR
(receiverid = ? AND senderid = ?)
```

This requires four parameter values. With numbered parameters, you can reuse them instead:

```
(senderid = ?1 AND receiverid = ?2) OR
(receiverid = ?1 AND senderid = ?2)
```

Comment: how to use this are condition into query?

Comment: Just like the original ones.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to doing a LIMIT (or a GROUP_BY) is to tack it onto the end of the SORT clause. For example, presuming you have your id column named senderId you could use the SORT clause `"senderid DESC LIMIT 10"`

Now I'm not sure what db is (probably the database directly) but you should be using a content provider so the params are 'uri, projection, selection, arguments, sort' and the following should be what you want

```
cursor = cp.query(Chat_MESSAGE, messagecolumns, "senderid=? AND " + "receiverid=?", new String[] { sender_id, receiver_id }, "senderid DESC LIMIT 10");
```

If this question arose because you don't know how to read the cursor jsut add a comment and I'll show you